# How to use a TypeScript generic function to enforce a property existing on a type passed in?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a generic type function that loops through an array of objects and references a property within that object. Obviously this means any array I pass in must have an array of objects that include the property "enforcedProperty". However I am unsure as to how to enforce this using an interface.

I have tried the following:

```
interface ObjectInterface {
  enforcedProperty: number;
}

type ArrayObjectInterface = ObjectInterface[];

function LoopObjects<T extends ArrayObjectInterface>(
  objectArray: T,
  enforcedProperty: number
): T | undefined {
  for (let i = objectArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
    if (enforcedProperty > objectArray[i].enforcedProperty) {
      if (i + 1 > objectArray.length - 1) {
        return objectArray[i];
      } else {
        return objectArray[i + 1];
      }
    } else if (i === 0) {
      return objectArray[0];
    }
  }
}
```

but this gives me the error: `Type 'ObjectInterface ' is not assignable to type 'T'.ts(2322)`

Comment: If you change return type to `ObjectInterface | undefined` and return `undefined` at the end, it will work.

Comment: @ford04 while that might silence the error, it will not take into account the actual type passed in, so whatever type you pass into the function you will get `ObjectInterface` on the other side of it which is usually undesirable.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir yeah, in this example it probably makes more sense to return the generic object type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you use `T` as the return type of the function, and `T` is the type of the array and you are trying to return an item of the array.

You could use `T[number]` represent the array item:

```
function LoopObjects<T extends ArrayObjectInterface>(
  objectArray: T,
  enforcedProperty: number
): T[number] | undefined { ... }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=10&ssc=25&pln=7&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFgJLjTxLIDeAUMshCDAPZRIAmAClHQA7RgCeAXMhABXALbpoAbnIBfcuV5dkAQShQ4PDNlwFIsRCgC8aLDnyE9SANoBdKeRhCQuYHRDIAMnU6bTAZwA8ACrUAB6QIEy+yqrqPtrmxBAAfAAUlMh0JrgqavzIgQA06TT0jBCs7FxQvALCYtDkAJQCgZZ14lDWyAA+yI5MEDCg5WTppcgpADYQYMjAyEaZWmA56gB00yAA5mAAFsgAtMgAjBJzyElGAAxn8wdGx42jVFTAMBMlDMxsnNw8FxksisYjxLMBrGtPmUKr9qjwnhQXi83hN5gBqE4ApamVY8DY0Hb7I6PZ5Il5QGZCKBubHZEFg2zpJHSaiTXwoRFkqgUsBUmlA3Fg5AY46MrmyZms9lzd4peYGBXIK4IpnkynUwHLQVXMUvCXIfU8vl9CKDYZMGRAA)

The better solution might be to have `T` represent the array item. It does not seem to me there is any reason to capture the array/tuple type as it will not be used in any significant way:

```
interface ObjectInterface {
  enforcedProperty: number;
}

function LoopObjects<T extends ObjectInterface>(
  objectArray: T[], 
  enforcedProperty: number
): T | undefined {
  for (let i = objectArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
    if (enforcedProperty > objectArray[i].enforcedProperty) {
      if (i + 1 > objectArray.length - 1) {
        return objectArray[i];
      } else {
        return objectArray[i + 1];
      }
    } else if (i === 0) {
      return objectArray[0];
    }
  }
  return undefined
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=21&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFgJLjTxLIDeAUMshCDAPZRIAmAClHQA7RgCeAXMhABXALbpoAbnIBfcuRhCQuYHRDIAMnU4ZsuAM4AeACrUAHpBBM9aLDnyFYiCAD4AFJWR1buAIJQocPzIRgDaALoANMgeNPSMEKzsXFC8AsJi0OQAlAImAD7IikwQMKAJZB5xyK4ANhBgyMDIALye3mB+ATwAdHUgAOZgABbIALTIAIwSjcjOrQAM002jrRNZFVRUwDDVsQzMbJzcPLNtuh3+gSHAYd178YlHKTzrFJub29VNANSTp17nTqBXo0QYjcZrDbvTZQepCKBqAF2IE8a5hKTQ5DSag1PQoN6Y5CwsDwxHtFHXZC-CbojzvWT0nF4xo7VxNZoc5DzV50mFwhFnZGXVHzWn0jwMon8tRFEplJgyIA)

Comment: Second solution worked perfectly for my situation, thanks.